# How to do subfigure top and bottom, and not left and right

Tags: subcaption

How to have a code for subfigure (a) and (b) in same line, not right and left

[image]

I had tried:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  % include first image
  \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{image_file_name}  
  \caption{Put your sub-caption here}
  \label{fig:sub-first}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  % include second image
  \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{image_file_name}  
  \caption{Put your sub-caption here}
  \label{fig:sub-second}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Put your caption here}
\label{fig:fig}
\end{figure}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please try to clarify your question? What output do you currently get and which alignment ot you want to have? Do you want the images to appear above each other instead of next to each other? Is this what  you want to achieve?  https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwtaH.png

Comment: To have images above each other, insert empty line between them.

Comment: And add `\centering` between `\begin{figure}[ht]` and `\begin{subfigure}` if you want to horizontally center the images.

Comment: @leandriis. Thanks. yes, that the image i want to achieve