# why added in \usepackage{subcaption} have error?

Tags: subcaption

I could not figure out what is the reason the error when I added in `\usepackage{subcaption}` in my main.tex for Overleaf.

[image]

Basically, I want to have [sub figure for one of my figure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/521989/how-to-do-subfigure-top-and-bottom-and-not-left-and-right?noredirect=1#comment1320065_521989)

My main.tex code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}  % Remove draft option to show figures (for final draft), otherwise keep for faster production




% to make the text width larger
\usepackage{geometry}
% to make the text width larger


% sub figure
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{subcaption}
% sub figure




% for drawing a table filled with color
\usepackage[svgnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hhline, boldline}
% for drawing a table filled with color

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{enumitem} % macros to modify appearance of 'itemize' environments
\usepackage{uorthesis}  % Loads the LaTeX style package

\usepackage[backend=biber, 
% style=authoryear, 
 style=authoryear-comp,
% citestyle=authoryear, 
dashed=false,
maxcitenames=2,
maxbibnames=99,
uniquelist=false, % for Author1 et al. (year) instead of Author1, Author2 et al. (year)
giveninits,
alldates=comp, %for online citing
dateabbrev=false, %for online citing for data format month in full
uniquename=init]{biblatex}

\urlstyle{same} % to make URL font style same

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given} %for second and third author name

\addbibresource{references.bib}
% \usepackage{uorbib}

% for combine both year for an author
% \DeclareDelimFormat{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
% 12-09-2019

% for a chapter edited by a book
\usepackage{xpatch}
% \renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addspace\&\space} 
% \renewcommand*{\intitlepunct}{\space} (to become In:)
\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\space} %to delete . after (1997)
% \DeclareFieldFormat[article, incollection, unpublished]{pages}{#1} % to add in PP. (page)
\DeclareFieldFormat[article, incollection, unpublished]{title}{#1}
% \renewcommand{\bibpagespunct}{\ifentrytype{article}{\addcolon}{\addperiod\addspace}} %cancel out this in order to add in PP. (page)


% for title italic
% \DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}} %for title italic in all format (conference, paper..)
\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{#1} %for conference title delete ".."
\DeclareFieldFormat[incollection]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}} %for incollecion title italic ONLY
\DeclareFieldFormat[thesis]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}} %for phdthesis title italic ONLY
\DeclareFieldFormat[book]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}} %for book title italic ONLY
% for title italic

% to delete "In:" for article
\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}{}{\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}
% to delete "In:" for article

% to make volume (number), eg. 4(2)
\newcommand*{\volnumdelim}{}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit*{\volnumdelim}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}

\newcommand*{\jourvoldelim}{\addcomma\space}
\newcommand*{\jourserdelim}{\newunitpunct}
\newcommand*{\servoldelim}{\jourvoldelim}
\newcommand*{\volnumdatedelim}{\addspace}

\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\jourvoldelim}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\setunit*{\jourserdelim}%
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit{\servoldelim}}%
  \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
  \setunit{\volnumdatedelim}%
  \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
  \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{issue}%
  \newunit}  
% to make volume (number), eg. 4(2)



% for delete comma after Author A and Aurhor b
\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}{%
   \let\finalandcomma\empty
   \let\finalandsemicolon\empty
 }

\renewcommand{\compcitedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\DeclareNameAlias{editorin}{given-family}

\newbibmacro*{byeditor:in}{%
  \ifnameundef{editor}
    {}
    {\printnames[editorin]{editor}%
     \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
     \usebibmacro{editorstrg}%
     \clearname{editor}}}     


\xpatchbibdriver{inbook}
  {\usebibmacro{in:}%
   \usebibmacro{bybookauthor}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}}
  {\usebibmacro{in:}%
   \usebibmacro{bybookauthor}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{byeditor:in}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}}
  {}{}

\xpatchbibdriver{incollection}
  {\usebibmacro{in:}%
   \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}}
  {\usebibmacro{in:}%
   \usebibmacro{byeditor:in}%
   \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
   \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{byeditor}}
  {}{}

\xpatchbibdriver{inproceedings}
  {\usebibmacro{in:}%
   \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{event+venue+date}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}}
  {\usebibmacro{in:}%
   \usebibmacro{byeditor:in}%
   \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
   \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{event+venue+date}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}}
  {}{}

\xpatchbibdriver{phdthesis}
  {\usebibmacro{in:}%
   \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{event+venue+date}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}}
  {\usebibmacro{in:}%
   \usebibmacro{byeditor:in}%
   \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
   \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{event+venue+date}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}}
  {}{}

% for the purpose to change "paper title" to 'paper title' in reference
\usepackage[style=british]{csquotes}
% \usepackage[style=english]{csquotes}
% for the purpose to change "paper title" to 'paper title' in reference


% for references 's studies (year)
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
\newcommand{\mycite}[1]{\citeauthor{#1}'s \citeyear{#1}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeauthor}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifciteindex
     {\indexnames{labelname}}
     {}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{\printnames{labelname}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeyear} % <======================================
    {}
    {(\bibhyperref{\printdate})}
    {\multicitedelim}
    {}

% for Quoting AuthorA (1999: 22), Part 2
% \DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite}[\mkbibparens]
%   {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
%   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
%   {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
%   \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{cite}}}
%   {\multicitedelim}
%   {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite}[\mkbibparens]
  {\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addcolon\space}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{cite}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\cbx@textcite}
  {\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addcolon\space}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:init}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{textcite}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{textcite:postnote}}
% for Quoting AuthorA (1999: 22), Part 2


\makeatletter
\let\abx@macro@textciteOrig\abx@macro@textcite
\renewbibmacro{textcite}{% <============================================
   \bibhyperref{%
   \let\bibhyperref\relax\relax%
   \abx@macro@textciteOrig%
   }%
}%
\makeatother
% for references 's studies (year)




% for Quoting AuthorA (1999: 22), Part 1
\DeclareDelimFormat[textcite]{postnotedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\DeclareDelimFormat[parencite]{postnotedelim}{\addcolon\space}

% \DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\printtext[bibhyperref]{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{#1}

% delete and replace above because of older version of biblatex
% \DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\mknormrange{#1}} 
% \DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{\mknormrange{#1}}
% delete and replace above because of older version of biblatex
% for Quoting AuthorA (1999: 22), Part 1





% %for changing URL to Available at: and title italic
% \usepackage[english]{babel}
% \usepackage[australian]{babel}
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{Available at\addcolon\space\url{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\mkbibbrackets{\bibstring{urlseen}\space#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[online]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
   urlseen = {Accessed},
}
% below is to keep 'english' format as babel
\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}{%
  \protected\def\mkdaterangecomp{%
    \mkdaterangetrunc{long}}%
  \protected\def\mkdaterangeterse{%
    \mkdaterangetrunc{short}}%
  \protected\def\mkdaterangecompextra{%
    \mkdaterangetruncextra{long}}%
  \protected\def\mkdaterangeterseextra{%
    \mkdaterangetruncextra{short}}%
  \protected\def\mkbibdatelong#1#2#3{%
    \iffieldundef{#3}
      {}
      {\thefield{#3}%
       \iffieldundef{#2}{}{\nobreakspace}}%
    \iffieldundef{#2}
      {}
      {\mkbibmonth{\thefield{#2}}%
       \iffieldundef{#1}{}{\space}}%
    \iffieldbibstring{#1}
      {\bibstring{\thefield{#1}}}
      {\dateeraprintpre{#1}\stripzeros{\thefield{#1}}}}%
}
% %for changing URL to Available at: and title italic


% For making book citing 2nd (subscript) and edn.
% --------------------------------------------------------------------
\DeclareFieldFormat[book]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\usepackage[raise]{fmtcount}

\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}{%
   \renewcommand*{\mkbibordedition}[1]{\ordinalnum{#1}[f]}
 }

 \DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
     edition = {edn\adddot},%
 }
% --------------------------------------------------------------------
% For making book citing 2nd (subscript) and edn.


\DeclareCiteCommand{\secondaryciteauthor}{}{\printtext[bibhyperref]{\printnames{labelname}}}{}{}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\secondaryciteyear}{}{\bibhyperref{\printdate}}{\multicitedelim}{}
\newcommand{\secondarycitedirect}[2]{\secondaryciteauthor{#1} (\secondaryciteyear{#1}, cited in \secondaryciteauthor{#2}, \secondaryciteyear{#2})}
\newcommand{\secondaryciteindirect}[2]{(\secondaryciteauthor{#1}, \secondaryciteyear{#1}, cited in \secondaryciteauthor{#2}, \secondaryciteyear{#2})}



% to add DOI as "Available at:" for @article
\DeclareFieldFormat{doi}{Available at\addcolon\space\url{#1}}
% can try below also
% \DeclareFieldFormat{doi}{\bibstring{urlfrom}\addcolon\space\url{#1}}
% \DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
%     urlfrom = {Available at}
% }
% to add DOI as "Available at:" for @article



\usepackage{enumitem} %for tab in Latex (macros to modify appearance of 'itemize' environments)
% Put custom packages to be loaded here
% \usepackage{linguex}  % For linguistic examples
% \usepackage{tikz}     % For drawing

%for section paragraph
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60209/how-to-add-an-extra-level-of-sections-with-headings-below-subsubsection
\makeatletter
%%%%% Change the style of paragraph headings %%%%%
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%  %for section paragraph
            {-2.5ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.25ex}%   %for section paragraph
            {1.25ex \@plus .25ex}%  %for section paragraph 
            {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}  %for section paragraph
%%%%% Change the style of subparagraph headings %%%%%
% \renewcommand\subparagraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%  %for section paragraph
%             {-2.5ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.25ex}%   %for section paragraph
%             {1.25ex \@plus .25ex}%  %for section paragraph 
%             {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}  %for section paragraph
\makeatother
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}

%for paragraph spacing
\setlength{\parindent}{4em} %for paragraph spacing
\setlength{\parskip}{1em} %for paragraph spacing
%for paragraph spacing

%for table spacing to second row
\usepackage{tabularx,seqsplit, caption} %for table spacing to second row
\usepackage{booktabs, ragged2e}       % Use booktabs rules and get rid of vertical rules, ragged2e to ragged text
\usepackage{makecell,siunitx} %for table spacing to second row
%for table spacing to second row

\usepackage{threeparttable} %to add footnote below table
\renewcommand{\TPTtagStyle}{\itshape} % optional
\usepackage{lipsum} % for filler text


% for bold in table using \small
\usepackage{makecell} % for bold in table using \small
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries} % for bold in table using \small
\usepackage{tabulary,siunitx} 
% for bold in table using \small 
\renewcommand\theadgape{}

% for df1 and df2 math symbol in bold
\usepackage{amsmath}
% for df1 and df2 math symbol in bold

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}








% \usepackage{libertine} %added by ryan


%\usepackage{float}
%\restylefloat{table}


%for table multirow
%\usepackage{multirow} %for table multirow
%\usepackage{multicol} %for table multirow
\usepackage{makecell, multirow, tabularx} %for table multirow
%for table multirow


\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calc, positioning,matrix,fit,calc, arrows.meta,
                backgrounds,
                chains}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}              % <---

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
% \usepackage{showframe}
% \renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
% \renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

% % for making a comma after the volume -> cancel off because it create journal title, 4.(1). 
% \renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
%   \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
%   \printfield{volume}%
%   \setunit*{\adddot}%
%   \printfield{number}%
%   \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
%   \printfield{eid}}


% \usepackage{parskip}  

\usepackage[hypcap=false]{caption}

% for the studies and hypothesis
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% for the studies and hypothesis


% for appendix
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

%New colors defined below
\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{codepurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}

%Code listing style named "mystyle"
\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
  backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},   commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
  keywordstyle=\color{magenta},
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
  stringstyle=\color{codepurple},
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
  breakatwhitespace=false,         
  breaklines=true,                 
  captionpos=b,                    
  keepspaces=true,                 
  numbers=left,                    
  numbersep=5pt,                  
  showspaces=false,                
  showstringspaces=false,
  showtabs=false,                  
  tabsize=2
}

%"mystyle" code listing set
\lstset{style=mystyle}
% for appendix




%  \usepackage{geometry}
%  \usepackage{tikz}
%  \usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc,positioning,fit}
%  \makeatletter
%  \newcommand{\WriteAux}[1]{%
%  \immediate\write\@mainaux{\xdef\string#1{#1}\relax}}
%  \makeatother
%  \pgfkeys{initialize dimension/.code={\unless\ifdefined#1
%   \def#1{0pt}
%   \fi}}



% \usetikzlibrary{fit,
%                 matrix}


% To change the default "PhD thesis" to "Ph.D. Thesis in Bibliography?
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{phdthesis = {Ph\adddot D\adddotspace Thesis}}
% To change the default "PhD thesis" to "Ph.D. Thesis in Bibliography?


\begin{document}

% Title page
\include{structure/title}

% All subsequent pages must be numbered, title page is considered page i,
% front matter is numbered in lowercase Roman numerals
\pagestyle{fancy}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{2}
\doublespacing

% Dedication (optional)
\include{structure/dedication}

% Acknowledgments
\include{structure/acknowledgements}

% Abstract
\include{structure/abstract}

% Table of Contents, List of Tables, List of Figures
\tableofcontents

%List of Tables & Figures
\include{structure/tablesfigures}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% DISSERTATION CONTENT %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Regular numbering starts now, first page of first chapter is page 1
\clearpage
\setcounter{page}{0}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

% Body


   \include{chapters/01-introduction}

   \include{chapters/02-background}

  \include{chapters/03-chapter}

   \include{chapter4/04-chapter}

  \include{chapters/05-chapter}

%   \include{chapters/06-chapter}

%   \include{chapters/07-chapter}

% \include{chapters/08-chapter}


%  \include{chapters/Full-06-chapter}  

%backup
% \include{chapters/04-chapter}

% References
\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\markboth{\MakeUppercase{Bibliography}}{}
%\singlespacing
\printbibliography
\appendix
\include{chapters/99-appendix}
\end{document}
```

and i need to use this below in template:

```
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage[subfigure]{tocloft} % subfigure option only if using subfigure package
```

Comment: The title page of the `subcaption` manual says `Please note: This package is incompatible with the subfigure and subfig packages.`. So these packages are mutually exclusive. They also serve the same purpose. You can do everything that `subfigure` allows you to do also with `subcaption`.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Thanks. Is it possible I can use `\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage[subfigure]{tocloft} % subfigure option only if using subfigure package
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\Huge \bfseries \sffamily} % ToC title`  to solve the issue of this here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/521989/how-to-do-subfigure-top-and-bottom-and-not-left-and-right?noredirect=1#comment1320065_521989

Comment: I do not think so but do you have the issue of "overnumbering" the figures if you use `subcaption`? If not, the problem is solved. If you do, this would make a very nice question: remove everything from the document but `\usepackage{subfigure} \usepackage[subfigure]{tocloft} \renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\Huge \bfseries \sffamily}` and provide a very crisp minimal document. But I think the problem is solved in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/129666).

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Thanks. That link is very useful. Thanks once again.

Comment: @Mico Thanks. I think you mean using `\usepackage{subcaption}` with `\usepackage{tocloft}` and it work both