# How to have subfigure listed in `List of Figure`?

Tags: subfloats

How to have subfigure listed in `List of Figure` like below:

[image]

I using a simple MWE shown below is working well.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[list=true]{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\chapter{One}
\section{One}

\begin{figure}[!b]
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.1\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
            \subcaption{$Q^{*}$ values for arm 1}
            \label{fig:arm1}
        \end{subfigure}
    %

        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.1\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
            \subcaption{$Q^{*}$ values for arm 2}
            \label{fig:arm2}
        \end{subfigure}


            \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.1\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
            \subcaption{$Q^{*}$ values for arm 3}
            \label{fig:arm2}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{$Q^{*}$ values for different arms}


          \end{figure}
    %

    \begin{figure}[htb]\ContinuedFloat
        \centering

        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.6\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
            \subcaption{$Q^{*}$ values for arm 4}
            \label{fig:arm3}
        \end{subfigure}
    %
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.6\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
            \subcaption{$Q^{*}$ values for arm 5}
            \label{fig:arm4}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{$Q^{*}$ values for different arms (cont.)}
        \label{fig:arms}
    \end{figure}


\end{document}
```

But, when I copy to a template [template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/university-of-rochester-masters-slash-phd-thesis-template/bwkpcxzdysky)

By adding

```
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[hypcap=false]{caption}
\usepackage[list=true]{subcaption}
```

It give an error:
[image]

Comment: The template seems to load the deprecated `subfigure` package that is in addition incompatible with the `subcaption` package that is used in the MWE. Do you definitely have to use that template?

Comment: Isn't this again the same/similar problem that was already discussed in the comments to one of your previous questions? [why added in \usepackage{subcaption} have error?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/522054/134144)

Comment: @leandriis, yes, because i had been using this template for my whole writing. Between, the link is not correct, But i know what is the link which i asked before, at the end, I didnt use the `\usepackage{subfigure}`. But this question here is new question

Comment: I've corrected the link. Thanks for pointing that out. However, the reason for the error message stays the same. Regarding: " at the end, I didnt use the \usepackage{subfigure}": As long as you use the `uorthesis` package, you also use `subfigure` since `uorthesis` loads `subfigure`. This also means, you can not use `uorthesis` in combination with `subcaption`.

Comment: @leandriis Thanks. You are correct. Brillant. Thanks once again. Can close this question or you can write an anwer, i can vote for it

Comment: I find it strange that a package from 2018/01/18 (uorthesis.sty) is still loading `subfigure` which is obsolete since 2003.